# What does the -> (point to member) operator do?

Tags: c++, pointers, operators

I have a linked list program,in which I see a lot of -> operators, but I don't know what they do.I searched about them here and there but all I found was that that is a point to member operator and that it does something ( I didn't completely understand what and why ).Here is a code snippet from the linked list, can you explain to me how this operator works?

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<class T>
class List{
struct Element{
    T data_;
    Element* next_;
    Element* prev_;

    Element(T val)
        :data_(val),
        next_(NULL),
        prev_(NULL)
        {}

};
Element* head_;
```

So this is the structure I am using and below is a simple push_back function.

```
void push_back(T val){
    Element* newElement = new Element(val);
    Element* back = head_->prev_;

    back->next_ = newElement;
    newElement->prev_ = back;

    newElement->next_ = head_;
    head_->next_ = newElement;
}

int main(){
    List<int> l;
    l.push_back(40);

    return 0;
}
```

Examples would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Which question(s) did you look at? What didn't you understand about it? I'd be surprised if there wasn't a very good answer on StackOverflow already.

Comment: @jerry what is the left and right side of it? I tried looking it up on google but I didn't manage to get a hold of what it does.

Comment: @EcoGiko: Please don't put junk like `[SOLVED]` in the title. Questions with an accepted answer are already styled differently in the UI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, the `->` operator is shorthand for dereferencing the pointer and accessing a member. 
The C
For example, given the declaration `Element* back`, then `back->next` is equivalent to `(*back).next`.

**EDIT:**

From Kernighan and Ritchie's *"The C Programming Language"*:

> Pointers to structures are so frequently used that an alternative notation is provided as a shorthand. If p is 
>   a pointer to a structure, then
>
> `p->member-of-structure`
>
> refers to the particular member.

Comment: Is there any point in using the -> operator?What is the difference between them?

Comment: One advantage is fewer parantheses to count, especially in longer expressions. Compare the readability and writability of a->b->c->d versus (*(*(*a).b).c).d .

Answer (score 3):

`->` *usually* Just works like this

```
foo->bar() ====> (*foo).bar()
```

This is all it does in your example.

However it can be overloaded per class so you can use it on things like `shared_ptr`. The only restriction is that you can only overload it to return a different pointer to dereference. Eg

```
class Foo {
      int* super_special_ptr;
    public:
      int* operator->(){ return super_special_ptr; }
};
```

Comment: I see.So they are identical?Does it just call the member?

Comment: Yes, it's just less finger work for using pointers to objects. It's pretty helpful since a goodly chunk of the time you're using pointers, you're avoiding object slicing